# Viewing vcard vcs email attachments

Tags: email, mu4e

I receive a couple of invitations to meetings from Microsoft Exchange users a week in my mailbox.  Is there a package with some mode I can install to make these attachments human readable or enhance `mu4e-view` to display at least the event start/end and location?

I don't need to import these things into some calendar like icalendar.el does.  I just want to view them.

Comment: While mainly a library Noah Friedman's [vcard.el](http://www.splode.com/~friedman/software/emacs-lisp/src/vcard.el) has a pretty-printer, `vcard-pretty-print`.

Comment: Nope, vcard.el can't parse vcalendar files.  The best solution I currently have is  setting up mailcap/mime/xdg (or whatever I did way back when) to open the file in emacs and running `icalendar-import-buffer` in it.

Comment: Bummer. In that case, I'd file a feature request against mu4e.

Comment: not what you asked for, but maybe [excorporate](https://github.com/emacsmirror/excorporate) can help you?

Comment: maybe you could [hack something](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnus-english/2011-10/msg00046.html) together yourself?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a better way then running `icalendar-import-buffer`. I am now using `mu4e-view-import-attachment-diary` instead (didn't notice this before..). Good enough for now.